# IE-7 z-index issue - Dropdown area going under banner and it's content not showing in IE-7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I created a testcase here http://testcases.site44.com/ in IE-7 dropdowns are not coming over banner image. in firefox and chrome it's fine.

Please help to find the issue.

Comment: can u make a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Very irritating approach of HTML in the mentioned link.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the `z-index` of `.megadrop` to something like `10000`

Comment: @A.K- i copied html from IE9 view source

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I have updated `z-index` of `.megadrop` to `10000` but no difference

Comment: I think you found the solution kindly post the answer

Comment: @jack - no problem is still there. Problem was in IE7

Comment: I was testing in ie8 problem was there too,but now its not in ie8, hope you will get solution for ie-7 too

Comment: @Jack - thanks for testing. please test with IE7 mode in IE8 if you can find the issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15162/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-jack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has a different approach in understanding z-index.
Besides the very irritating approach of HTML in the mentioned link, you should do the following:

if you have 2 divs, and in the first one there is something that should go over content in the second one, than you need to set z-index on both of them, and a higher value for the one that has the content that goes over the other.

example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul id="flyout">
 //
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
 //
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {position:relative;z-index:2;}
#flyout {position:relative;z-index:3;}
#content {position:relative;z-index:1;}
```

IE now understands that the content in the first div should go over the content in the second div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put yours element **id="footer"** with a higher z-index than **id="main"**

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`z-index:1` from div id="banner" do this changes for ie-7 only

in-fact only `z-index:1`is affecting for ie-7

[image]

Comment: I've changed z-index:0 for IE7 but it's not making any difference

Comment: let me show you the Screen shot,plz clear browser cache might be this causing no change,

Comment: I solved the problem even by having `z-index:1` from div id="banner"